# Downloading file with DownloadManager Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to download a file using the DownloadManager inside an AsyncTask

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{

    private Context mContext;

    public DownloadTask(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {


        String fileName = strings[2]+"_"+strings[3]+ strings[4];
        String destination = mDestination + fileName;
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);
        mDownloading = true;
        //If the file is already downloading just return.
        File file = new File(destination);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return true;
        }



        //set downloadmanager
        DownloadManager.Request request = new    DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(strings[0]));        
        request.setDescription(mContext.getString(R.string.downloading)+ " "+strings[1]);
        request.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.downloading_title));

        //set destination
        request.setDestinationUri(uri);

        // get download service and enqueue file
        final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);


        //set BroadcastReceiver to enable next download
        BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
                unregisterReceiver(this);
                mDownloading = false;
            }
        };
        //register receiver for when file download is compete
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        return true;
    }
}`
```

The code works fine when I pass the url of the file. The thing is, that we want to make a GET call to a WEB made on PHP. This WEB method creates or selects a file and redirects using  header`("Location: ".$database->single()['Url']);`

But when we make the call from DownloadManager it just calls registerReceiver right away.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

If we use a `HttpURLConnection` it works fine, but we would like to delegate all the hard work of the download in the DownloadManager.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Don't have answer but try download using this libraray : https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5196

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, for me, I got exact same results using Fetch. Great discovery though.

Answer (score 0):

**3xx: redirects is't supported by DownloadManger.** [Source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/provider/Downloads.java) at line 510

And it will download the redirect response and finish right way.

So you should get the response head[Location] by yourself, and pass it to the task.

---

By the way, you needn't put the download task in the AsyncTask.